# Python PodSixNet Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, multiplayer

I'm trying to use a multiplayer module called PodSixNet to use in one of my games, but I get an error in `assyncore.py` when trying to run the client. However, the server works flawlessly. I developed simple test client and server programs, but I still get the same error when I run the client. Here are my client and server programs respectively:

```
import PodSixNet, time
from PodSixNet.Connection import ConnectionListener, connection
from time import sleep

class MyNetworkListener(ConnectionListener):

    connection.Connect()


    def Network(self, data):
        print data


gui = MyPlayerListener()
while 1:
    connection.Pump()
    gui.Pump()
```

.

```
import PodSixNet, time
from time import sleep
from PodSixNet.Channel import Channel
from PodSixNet.Server import Server

class ClientChannel(Channel):

    def Network(self, data):
        print data

class MyServer(Server):

    channelClass = ClientChannel

    def Connected(self, channel, addr):
        print "new connection:", channel

myserver = MyServer()

while True:
    myserver.Pump()
    sleep(0.0001)
```

And here is the error I'm returned when I run the client:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\The 37th Battalion\PodSixNet Tests\client.py",  line 5, in <module>
        class MyNetworkListener(ConnectionListener):
      File "C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\The 37th Battalion\PodSixNet Tests\client.py",   line 7, in MyNetworkListener
    connection.Connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\asyncore.py", line 418, in __getattr__
    retattr = getattr(self.socket, attr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\asyncore.py", line 418, in __getattr__
    retattr = getattr(self.socket, attr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\asyncore.py", line 418, in __getattr__
    retattr = getattr(self.socket, attr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\asyncore.py", line 418, in __getattr__
    retattr = getattr(self.socket, attr)
```

This error continues until I reach maximum recursion depth. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to tell the server which port it should listen on:

**server.py**

```
import PodSixNet, time
from time import sleep
from PodSixNet.Channel import Channel
from PodSixNet.Server import Server

class ClientChannel(Channel):

    def Network(self, data):
        print data

class MyServer(Server):

    channelClass = ClientChannel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Server.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def Connected(self, channel, addr):
        print "new connection:", channel

# use the localaddr keyword to tell the server to listen on port 1337
myserver = MyServer(localaddr=('localhost', 1337))

while True:
    myserver.Pump()
    sleep(0.0001)
```

Then, the client has to connect to this port:

**client.py**

```
import PodSixNet, time
from PodSixNet.Connection import ConnectionListener, connection
from time import sleep

class MyNetworkListener(ConnectionListener):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.Connect((host, port))

    def Network(self, data):
        print data

# tell the client which server to connect to
gui = MyNetworkListener('localhost', 1337)
while 1:
    connection.Pump()
    gui.Pump()
```

You don't have to call `Connect()` on `connection`, but on the `ConnectionListener` instance.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks! Your examples worked flawlessly. I'm very gracious for your assistance!